# Can someone point to me to the right direction but leading me with questions to ask myself to solve this error for my hw

Tags: ruby

So when I run my lab i am getting the following error:

1. Associations — Song and Artist: Artist #add_song adds the song to the current artist's 'songs' collection

   ```
    Failure/Error: expect(artist.songs).to include(song)
   expected ["In the Aeroplane Over the Sea"] to include #<Song:0x0000000001496e88 @name="In the Aeroplane Over the Sea", @artist=#<Artist:0x0000000001496f50 @name="Neutral Milk Hotel", @songs=["In the Aeroplane Over the Sea"]>>
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -[#<Song:0x0000000001496e88 @name="In the Aeroplane Over the Sea", @artist=#<Artist:0x0000000001496f50 @name="Neutral Milk Hotel", @songs=["In the Aeroplane Over the Sea"]>>]
   +["In the Aeroplane Over the Sea"]
   ```

But when I run my code through pry, I can see the song added into the array of the instance variable, @songs. I am working with two classes, a song class and artist class.

```
class Artist 
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_reader :songs 
  @@all = [] 
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name 
    save
    @songs = []
  end
  def self.all 
    @@all 
  end
  def save 
    @@all << self 
  end
  def self.destroy_all
    @@all.clear
  end
  def self.create(name)
    self.new(name)
  end
  def add_song(song)
     if song.artist == nil
      song.artist = self
    end 
    #checks if the same song has already been added, otherwise adds new song
    if @songs.include?(song.name) == false 
      @songs << song.name
    end
   binding.pry
  end
end

class Song 
  attr_accessor :name, :artist
  @@all =[]
  def initialize(name, artist = nil) 
    @name = name
    @artist = artist
    save
  end
  def self. all 
    @@all 
  end
  def save 
    @@all << self 
  end
  def self.destroy_all
    @@all.clear 
  end
  def self.create(name)
    self.new(name)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tests are expecting an aray of `Song` instances. But what they find is an array of strings.

To fix it you'd just need to change `@songs << song.name` to `@songs << song`.

I am sorry if I just *gave you the answer* instead of hinting you along to solve it yourself, but this isn't really the right platform for that kind of thing. Every question on StackOverflow can be searched by users and we want to keep things helpful to them by getting straight to the point.

However, I can give some advice. Practice reading errors. Try and understand what the error is telling you.

Comment: of course thanks for the advice!! I think i see it now. I am calling on the object instead of the instance since name is the method on which the song is receiving it.